# Share in-app purchase across apps on a single device

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm thinking about building a series of iOS apps. 
Each app will be purchased individually but I'd like in-app purchases within any of the apps to be universal. ie, pay for it in one app of the series, it's available in any other apps installed to use too.
Is this possible without forcing the user to create an account of any sort?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing the title! That makes much more sense.

Comment: Actually you could do that with the use of iCloud stored data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is NO, Reason is all your IAP are identified by the bundle identifier and that is unique for each application, as all the IAP's are specific to the bundle identifier you can not share those.

There is another way of achieving what you asking for, I don't know all your requirements still I would NOT follow this solution, still I am writing to know some options.

You can sharing the keychain across the applications and keep track of purchases across apps.

1. Keychain data is not deleted on deletion of the app
2. If user resets/restore phone keychain data can get deleted and you will be at dead end, as user has to restore the content from your 1st application to use in 2nd application... (yeah confusing.. right ?)

There may be some other complications I am missing right now.. good luck